# How to mock method properly to return specific data when checking other method with Autofac.Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac, dapper

Have such C# code and try to check method IsFailureProcessStatus to return true.
Query method from dapper class SqlMapper which call stored procedures with parameters.

```
public class DatabaseManager : IDatabaseManager
{
        private readonly SqlConnection CoreDbProcessesConnection;
        private readonly SqlConnection HrReportDbConnection;
        // there are other private fields with parameters and sql-procedures names

        public DatabaseManager(IDbConnectionsProvider dbConnectionsProvider)
        {
            this.CoreDbProcessesConnection = dbConnectionsProvider.CoreDbProcessesConnection;
            this.HrReportDbConnection = dbConnectionsProvider.HrReportDbConnection;
        }

        public List<CoreProcessStatusDto> GetProcessStatusIds(string ProcessName, DateTime dateTime)
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add(processStatusProcedureParamName01, ProcessName);
            parameters.Add(processStatusProcedureParamName02, dateTime);

            var output = this.CoreDbProcessesConnection
                .Query<CoreProcessStatusDto>(ProcessStatusProcedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

            return output;
        }

        public bool IsFailureProcessStatus(StepDto.StepDescription step, DateTime dateTime)
        {
            bool isStepFailure = true;

            Stopwatch doStepUntil = new Stopwatch();
            doStepUntil.Start();

            while (doStepUntil.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(step.SecondsElapsed))
            {

                step.StatusTypesList = this.GetProcessStatusIds(step.ProcessName, dateTime);
                var statusTypesStepSelection = step.StatusTypesList.Select(st => st.ProcessStatusTypeId).ToList();

                //...
                // if...else operations here to make step true or false
                //...
            }

            doStepUntil.Stop();

            return isStepFailure;
       }
}
```

Unit test code is located below:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class DatabaseManagerTests
    {
       [TestMethod]
        public void IsFailureProcessStatus_ReturnTrue()
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

            StepDto step1Dto = new StepDto()
            {
                JobName = "ETL - HR - FilesImport - Reporting",
                JobStepName = "RunMCP_User_Department_Map",
                Step = new StepDto.StepDescription()
                {
                    StatusTypesList = new List<CoreProcessStatusDto>(),
                    ProcessName = "HR_User_Department_Map_Import",
                    SecondsElapsed = 30,
                    PackageCount = 2
                }
            };

            using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
            {
                var dbProviderMock = new Mock<IDbConnectionsProvider>(MockBehavior.Loose);

                var dbMock = new Mock<DatabaseManager>(dbProviderMock.Object);

                mock.Mock<IDatabaseManager>()
                    .Setup(p => p.GetProcessStatusIds(step1Dto.Step.ProcessName, dateTime))
                    .Returns(GetCoreProcessesStatusIdsTest());

                var sut = mock.Provide(dbMock.Object);

                //var sut = mock.Create<DatabaseManager>();

                var actual = sut.IsFailureProcessStatus(step1Dto.Step, dateTime);

                Assert.IsTrue(actual);
            }
        }

        private List<CoreProcessStatusDto> GetCoreProcessesStatusIdsTest()
        {
            var output = new List<CoreProcessStatusDto>()
            {
                new CoreProcessStatusDto() { ProcessStatusTypeId = 3 },
                new CoreProcessStatusDto() { ProcessStatusTypeId = 2 }
            };

            return output;
        }
    }
```

I tried to setup GetProcessStatusIds method to return values when calling sut.IsFailureProcessStatus code, but while debug its run GetProcessStatusIds and throw NullReferenceException exception when try calling Query method.

```
Test Name:  IsFailureProcessStatus_ReturnTrue
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StackTrace:  
at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__140`1.MoveNext() in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 1066
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 721
   at ATP.HR.FolderWatcher.Service.Managers.DatabaseManager.GetProcessStatusIds(String ProcessName, DateTime dateTime) in C:\HOME\anatolii.dmitryv\src\HRM\hr-folder-watcher-service\ATP.HR.FolderWatcher.Service\Managers\DatabaseManager.cs:line 46
   at ATP.HR.FolderWatcher.Service.Managers.DatabaseManager.IsFailureProcessStatus(StepDescription step, DateTime dateTime) in C:\HOME\anatolii.dmitryv\src\HRM\hr-folder-watcher-service\ATP.HR.FolderWatcher.Service\Managers\DatabaseManager.cs:line 83
   at ATP.HR.FolderWatcher.Service.Test.DatabaseManagerTests.IsFailureProcessStatus_ReturnTrue() in C:\HOME\anatolii.dmitryv\src\HRM\hr-folder-watcher-service\ATP.HR.FolderWatcher.Service.Tests\DatabaseManagerTests.cs:line 57
Result Message: 
Test method ATP.HR.FolderWatcher.Service.Test.DatabaseManagerTests.IsFailureProcessStatus_ReturnTrue threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

And what exactly I do wrong in mock of this method? How I can say to test do not run this GetProcessStatusIds and just return hardcoded values?

tried this using but it didnt work for me:

```
using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
{

      mock.Mock<IDatabaseManager>()
          .Setup(p => p.GetProcessStatusIds(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
          .Returns(GetCoreProcessesStatusIdsTest());

          var sut = mock.Create<DatabaseManager>();

          var actual = sut.IsFailureProcessStatus(step1Dto.Step, dateTime);

          Assert.IsTrue(actual);
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure, can you try replacing GetCoreProcessesStatusIdsTest() with a lambda? () => GetCoreProcessesStatusIdsTest(). Or try saying sut = new Mock<IDatabaseManager> and do the setup for the mock. then call sut.Object.IsFailureProcessStatus(...)

Comment: @GlennvanAcker lambda didn't work for me. With sut.Object after setup it is always returning false and never goes inside the method while debugging.

Comment: have you tried making a mock of an IDatabaseManager, rather than a DatabaseManager. i think that might have something to do with it. I Also think creating the Mock with Mock.Create after you've setup a mock for an interface can have undesirable results. (Not sure about this as i'm having trouble finding good documentation on that)

Comment: Take a look at the example here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/moq.html
Here they are using Automock.CreateLoose to inject mocked dependencies in the constructor. but they are mocking the actual object, rather than the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing when doing unit testing is to define the goal of the test, in your question you are trying to test the **inside** logic of `IsFailureProcessStatus`, the  problem here is that you mocking the interface `IDatabaseManager` that has the `IsFailureProcessStatus` method.

You don't need that mocking, you will only will need to mock `IDatabaseManager` when it uses as supplier for other clients services.

And because you are testing the inside logic of `IsFailureProcessStatus` you will only need to mock and setup method that are needed for the execution of the inside logic like `IDbConnectionsProvider` and setup its method of `CoreDbProcessesConnection` for it to be available to the `DatabaseManager` real instance.

```
var dbProviderMock = new Mock<IDbConnectionsProvider>(MockBehavior.Loose);

dbProviderMock
    .Setup(p => p.CoreDbProcessesConnection)
    .Returns(new SqlConnection(...));

DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(dbProviderMock.Object);

var actual = databaseManager.IsFailureProcessStatus(step1Dto.Step, dateTime);

Assert.IsTrue(actual);
```

I can understand why you wrongly tried to mock `GetProcessStatusIds`, but it won't needed since we have the real instance of `DatabaseManager`, so you will only be mocking depended interfaces that are needed in the execution process of `GetProcessStatusIds`, thats why we does not need here the setup of `HrReportDbConnection`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my case I created new class DataAccess and mock through IDataAccess (and ofc added it in DatabaseManager constructor). In this new class I moved GetProcessStatusIds method and other methods that use IDbConnectionsProvider with connection to DB... so I can easily to create sut for DatabaseManager and test is fine now